# How to connect to NAO robot using sockets?

Tags: sockets, nao-robot

I'm playing with Aldebaran's [NAO humanoid robot Simulator](http://www.aldebaran-robotics.com/en/Discover-NAO/Software/NAOsim.html)  and choregraph.
I have a software in java that I would like to use to control the robot by activating its behaviors, and I believe sockets would do the trick.

My question is: is there a way to open a socket connection from within choregraph+naoSim, so I can get sensor readings and send commands to the robot?
Or any other way to connect to choregraph+naoSim to achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 1):

I'm planning to use python websocket package to accomplish this. As far as I see the server can be written on anything. The client part - NAO - should initiate connection to the server send something, possibly wait for a reply and then carry on. So the sending functionality can be implemented using Python and coded in one of the NAO action boxes. You could even create a separate box that will take a request as a parameter and output a reply from the server. A small neat box that talk to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! :)

I tried doing that but when I "import socket" it complains it couldn't find the library.

 I talked to aldebaran suport and they told me it did not work because choregraph doesn't have this library available. They said the right way of doing that is to use their SDK.

 Unfortunately, you can only download the sdk after previouslly buying a NAO unit. Which I only intend to do if I'm sure I can use it with my project (by using the demo version first). 

 So, I'm in a deadlock situation here. :) 

Did you manage to do it the way you suggested?

Comment: Well the SDK looks really powerful. Unfortunately I wasn't able to use it successfully because my robot is too old for SDK :( 
There are several options:
Write a Python or C++ module and programmatically tell the robot what to do. In this case you connect to the robot with IP address and a port number. And then you can do whatever you want.
The function calls are encapsulated in SOAP messages that are sent to the robot. So you can even analyze the traffic and wrap you commands in SOAP messages on your own.

Comment: What would you use to make this connection? I tried using Java sockets both in TCP and UDP modes to no avail. :(

Comment: Well it's simple if you have SDK. Have you got one?